# How to convert parquet to json

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, parquet, fastparquet

I have parquet files hosted on S3 that I want to download and convert to JSON. I was able to use select_object_content to output certain files as JSON using SQL in the past. I need to find a faster way to do it because it is timing out for larger files.

I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_parquet(s3_location)
df = df.to_json(orient="records")
```

However, the JSON output from the above code includes the key paths (hotels.date.hotel_price INSTEAD OF hotels:{date:{hotel_price: 100}}.

Anyone know of a way to do this so that it comes out as the second type of JSON?

Comment: stay out of pandas unless you need it

Comment: Import pyarrow.paraquet as pq \n pq.read_table('df.parquet').to_pydict()

Comment: Also, Polars supports pagination with it's use of the Rust paraquat reader. https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_parquet.html

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late of a response but for anyone else who runs into this same issue the easiest way is to download this parquet-viewer extension in VS Code and you will be able to preview your data as JSON.

Link to Extension for reference
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dvirtz.parquet-viewer